# Inversion Power Loss For Powering Home Electronics

Tags: power-supply, mains, efficiency

I had a question about power loss for powering home electronics/appliances. 
 Let's say in your home/shed you had various electronics that you want to power that all take DC (printer/tv/etc.), and you had your own means for generating power like solar or hydroelectric. From what I've been reading online, people who have their own means of generating their own electricity generally tend to store everything in big batteries and then when they need to power something, they power it with the standard AC power plugs/sockets through an inverter from the batteries. 
 From my background knowledge, DC electronics are powered from the standard AC power sockets which are then converted to DC through the adapter block or whatever, and so you can treat it as a black box if you exclude the AC part and only focus on powering the DC parts. 
 My question is instead of using an inverter to power something just to change it back to DC (power loss from conversion), wouldn't it be more efficient if you converted the power supply of your electronics to only take a specific DC power input? Doing so would mean you would have to make a modified input for the electronics and a modified source (socket for example) for powering them, but is it really worth the hassle to save the energy? If not, how much power is lost through the conversion of DC to AC back to DC, and is there anything that could be done to cut down on the power loss? 
I apologize if there are gaps in my knowledge I don't have much experience in this. Any info back would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a note, that *some* switch-mode power supplies will take DC input.  Get their model numbers and research their datasheets.  In switchers, internally AC is rectified to DC anyways, so using straight DC will be slightly more efficient.  The down-side is that you need to wire 150-320, even 690VDC to these, which is very dangerous.  Consult an electrician specializing in these (energy storage, DC) for local and accurate information.

Comment: I did not know that, and I will definitely look into it!

Comment: yes, if you can keep it all in the DC realm, it's more efficient. AC-DC is fairly efficient these days for most power bricks and wall warts, 90-95%. DC-AC inversion is also about 90-95%. That means if you replace both parts with an SMPS that's 98% efficient and don't have long power cords, you can get 8-18% more battery life "for free". You can go piecemeal too, replacing anything with a ac-dc power supply that gets warm with a DC-DC converter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, converting power is always inefficient and has losses. So at first glance it would make sense to omit the conversion from DC to mains AC and back to DC for devices.

However, you already have the necessary infrastructure for distributing mains, and the mains adapters for each device. Converting each device separately to be powered from the batteries directly is also costly. Distributing low voltage is also costly, as you don't have the infrastructure for it. Cables, plugs, and DC/DC converters all come with a cost.

The amount of power loss can't be approximated or calculated without measurements, it is indeterminate. In some parts of the world there might be rules how efficient power supplies are required to be, so they don't waste energy as heat.

And usually there is no common standard for what voltages or what plugs to use for low voltage distribution so if you make something you are on your own.

Outside of home/shed environment, for example in data centers, there are standards for DC powered computer equipment and DC power distribution, to have a single large efficient mains to DC converter e.g. for a rack of dozen computers, instead of wasting space for dozen of smaller and less efficient mains input power supplies.

Comment: OK so power loss can't approximated without the necessary measurements, I can do my own measurements to find out the necessary information. Disregarding the rules, if I were to make something on my own even with a potentially large upfront cost for the appropriate infrastructure (step-down converters/plugs/etc.), how would I be able to determine if it would be worth it in the long run? Like lets say if i was running a solar panel and no inverter but with my own plugs and converters, I would still need to make the necessary measurements to see if I consider it worth it?

Comment: Yes, and consider also that getting high reliability and high efficiency means high cost. If your custom converter malfunctions after a week and destroys your new laptop and everything connected to it, will it be not worth it. Using the official mains adapter from manufacturer might be worth it.